# IAP Non-Renewing Subscription Restore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am building an application which has In App Purchases and Non-Renweing Subscriptions, everything is working fine in terms of purchasing and me storing the users expiration date on our servers however I am a little confused to what should happen when it comes to restoring subscriptions.

Apple states that we should manage the restore process via our own server which we can do fine but I am wondering what purpose is served calling Store Kit restoreCompletedTransactions?

Is this step actually required or could I just have the app call my own web server to restore in the subscription?

Just wanting to make sure I have the steps correct before I submit this over to Apple.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

restoreCompletedTransactions will return nothing as it acts like a consumable.  Your own server is the only restoration mechanism.

However..... Apple do require you to not force users to sign up with an email address so users may/can actually lose their subscription.

Comment: Cheers Lee, That what I read about it also so is there any point in my calling it when restore is tapped?  Just want to make sure Apple don't expect the user to login with their apple ID when restore is tapped.  The app itself requires users to sign up to use it or login its currently on the store